# Concatenation of date & time columns and assignment to index

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have this data

```
               Date   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
0      2013.07.09   7:00  101.056  101.151  101.016  101.130    1822
1      2013.07.09   8:00  101.130  101.257  101.128  101.226    2286
2      2013.07.09   9:00  101.226  101.299  101.175  101.180    2685
3      2013.07.09  10:00  101.178  101.188  101.019  101.154    2980
```

And I combine Date and Time to be this

```
                 Datetime  
0     2013-07-09 07:00:00  
1     2013-07-09 08:00:00
```

So i want to replace DateTime into Date and Time in my data and also it's index. The result that I expect looks like this

```
Datetime     Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Csv for PYthon\USDJPY60.csv")
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(str)+' '+df['Time'])
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters `index_col` and `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) only:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Csv for PYthon\USDJPY60.csv"), 
                   index_col=['Date_Time'],
                   parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])

print (df)
                        Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
Date_Time                                                      
2013-07-09 07:00:00  101.056  101.151  101.016  101.130    1822
2013-07-09 08:00:00  101.130  101.257  101.128  101.226    2286
2013-07-09 09:00:00  101.226  101.299  101.175  101.180    2685
2013-07-09 10:00:00  101.178  101.188  101.019  101.154    2980
```

But if need `Time` column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Csv for PYthon\USDJPY60.csv"), 
                   index_col=['Date'],
                   parse_dates=['Date'])

df.index = df.index + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'] + ':00')
print (df)
                      Time     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
2013-07-09 07:00:00   7:00  101.056  101.151  101.016  101.130    1822
2013-07-09 08:00:00   8:00  101.130  101.257  101.128  101.226    2286
2013-07-09 09:00:00   9:00  101.226  101.299  101.175  101.180    2685
2013-07-09 10:00:00  10:00  101.178  101.188  101.019  101.154    2980
```

And for index only (both columns are not changed):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+' '+df['Time'])
print (df)
                           Date   Time     Open     High      Low    Close  \
2013-07-09 07:00:00  2013.07.09   7:00  101.056  101.151  101.016  101.130   
2013-07-09 08:00:00  2013.07.09   8:00  101.130  101.257  101.128  101.226   
2013-07-09 09:00:00  2013.07.09   9:00  101.226  101.299  101.175  101.180   
2013-07-09 10:00:00  2013.07.09  10:00  101.178  101.188  101.019  101.154   

                     Volume  
2013-07-09 07:00:00    1822  
2013-07-09 08:00:00    2286  
2013-07-09 09:00:00    2685  
2013-07-09 10:00:00    2980
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: what return invalid syntax? What solution do you use?

Comment: @jezrael Lol... when OP wants help but is not willing to help you help them

Comment: runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Downloads/Compressed/course3_downloads/untitled7.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Downloads/Compressed/course3_downloads')
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Downloads/Compressed/course3_downloads/untitled7.py", line 5
    df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Csv for PYthon\USDJPY60.csv",index_col=['Datetime'],parse_dates=[['Date','Time']]))
                                                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @KornTawe - It seems nice, try rewrite code again, because maybe some bad character is copied. It obviously help.

Comment: I use the first one

Comment: Or you can use instead `index_col=['Date_Time'],
                   parse_dates=[['Date','Time']])` use `index_col=[0],
                   parse_dates=[[0,1]])` for select columns by positions.

Comment: Ok it's work. But there is some mistake in your parenthesis position after .csv Thank you so much. Can you edit it? I try but it seems like I have to edit more than 6 characters or something.

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!